# How to stop asynchronous function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I have some asynchronous problems. I'm working on an [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) object. It's a timer and I want to be able to restart during its countdown.

Here is my work:

```
export class Timer {
    constructor(sec){
        this.sec = sec;
        this.count = sec;
        this.running = false;
    }

    start() {
        this.running = true;
        this._run();
    }

    _run(){
        if(this.running){
            setTimeout(()=>{
                this.count --;
                console.log(this.count);
                if(this.count<0){
                    this.running = false;
                }
                this._run();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    restart(){
        this.running = false;
        /*
            Wait until _run() is done then :
        */
        this.count = this.sec;
        this.start();
    }
}
```

In the `restart()` function, how can I know when `_run()` has stopped running?

Comment: You seem to already be maintaining the running state with the `running` field. Couldn't you just query it's state? In the `restart` method, instead of changing the `running` field to false, you could just check if that's already the case.

Comment: Do you only want to *know whether* it has stopped running, or do you really need to *await* it?

Comment: Most of the time, running returns to true before setTimeout() is done.

Comment: @Bergi Well start() can start a new recursive process of _run(). They will both run in same time.

Comment: @DanyBoisvert: And that's a problem, because they're not really running "both". Rather, your single `Timer` instance is running at double speed :-) The cleaner solution would probably be to create a new instance. How are you using these actually? I currently can't see what they *do*, as they never emit any messages back to the caller.

Comment: @DanyBoisvert: What I'm asking for is whether you want the `(re)start` calls to *queue up*, or whether you just want to *detect* if it is still running and handle that somehow (without starting anything).

Comment: @Bergi I want the (re)start calls to queue up

Comment: Then you'll have to build a queue (or a queue counter) that is pushed to when `.running` is still true, and do the restart when your `_run` has finished (i.e. instead of setting `running` to false)

Comment: That should fix my needs. I will use the timer and see weather or not i'll need to track the _run() process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to know if the timer is "running" is to perhaps use `setInterval` instead.

```
var interval = setInterval(() => updateTimer(), 10); // update every 10ms
```

It's running if `interval` is set

```
if (interval) // timer is running
```

Stop the timer

```
window.clearInterval(interval);
interval = null;
// timer is no longer "running"
```

---

Additional notes

> Beware of creating timers that increment with a fixed value

In your code, you have

```
setTimeout(() => this.count--, 1000);
```

The intention is for you to decrement your `count` property once every second, but this is not the behavior you will be guaranteed.

Check out this little script

```
var state = {now: Date.now()};

function delta(now) {
  let delta = now - state.now;
  state.now = now;
  return delta;
}

setInterval(() => console.log(delta(Date.now())), 1000);

// Output
1002
1000
1004
1002
1002
1001
1002
1000
```

We used `setInterval(fn, 1000)` but the actual interval varies a couple milliseconds each time.

The problem is exaggerated if you do things like switch your browser's focus to a different tab, open a new tab, etc. Look at these more sporadic numbers

```
1005 // close to 1000 ms
1005 // ...
1004 // a little variance here
1004 // ...
1834 // switched focus to previous browser tab
1231 // let timer tab run in background for a couple seconds
1082 // ...
1330 // ...
1240 // ...
2014 // switched back to timer tab
1044 // switched to previous tab
2461 // rapidly switched to many tabs below
1998 // ...
2000 // look at these numbers...
1992 // not even close to the 1000 ms that we set for the interval
2021 // ...
1989 // switched back to this tab
1040 // ...
1003 // numbers appear to stabilize while this tab is in focus
1004 // ...
1005 // ...
```

So, this means you can't rely upon your `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) function getting run once per `1000` ms. `count` will be decremented with much variance depending on a wide variety of factors.

To work around this, you need to use a delta. That means before each "tick" of your timer, you need to take a timestamp using `Date.now`. On the next tick, take a new timestamp and subtract your previous timestamp from the new one. That is your `delta`. Using this value, add it to the Timer's total `ms` to get the *precise* number of milliseconds the timer has been running for.

Then, all time-sensitive values will be a projection/calculation of the total accumulated ms.

In your case, say you have a `count` that starts at `10`. If you want to count down by `-1` each `1000` ms, you could do

```
function update() {
  // update totalMs
  this.totalMs += calculateDelta();
  // display count based on totalMS
  console.log("count %d", Math.ceil(this.count - this.totalMs/1000));
}
```

---

Here's a sample ES6 timer that implements a `delta` function that might help you

```
class Timer {
  constructor(resolution=1000, ms=0) {
    this.ms = ms
    this.resolution = resolution;
    this.interval = null;
  }
  delta(now) {
    let delta = now - this.now;
    this.now = now;
    return delta;
  }
  start() {
    this.now = Date.now();
    this.interval = window.setInterval(() => this.update(), this.resolution);
  }
  reset() {
    this.update();
    this.ms = 0;
  }
  stop() {
    this.update();
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = null;
  }
  update() {
    this.ms += this.delta(Date.now());
    console.log("%d ms - %0.2f sec", this.ms, this.ms/1000);
  }
}
```

Create a new timer with a `50` ms "resolution". All this means is that the timer display is updated every 50 ms. You could set this value to anything and the timer will still keep an accurate value.

```
var t = new Timer(50);
t.start();
```

To simulate the reset, we can just create a one-off timeout so you can see the reset working

```
// in ~5 seconds, reset the timer once
setTimeout(() => t.reset(), 5000);
```

Here's a demonstration of pausing the timer

```
// in ~10 seconds, pause the timer
setTimeout(() => t.stop(), 10000);
```

And you can resume the timer, too

```
// in ~12 seconds, resume the timer (without reset)
setTimeout(() => t.start(), 12000);
```

You can `start`, `stop`, `reset` the timer as much as you like

---

Here's an the ES6 (above) transpiled to ES5 so you can see the code working in a runnable snippet. Open your console and click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd>.

```js
"use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Timer = (function () {
  function Timer() {
    var resolution = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? 1000 : arguments[0];
    var ms = arguments.length <= 1 || arguments[1] === undefined ? 0 : arguments[1];

    _classCallCheck(this, Timer);

    this.ms = ms;
    this.resolution = resolution;
    this.interval = null;
  }

  Timer.prototype.delta = function delta(now) {
    var delta = now - this.now;
    this.now = now;
    return delta;
  };

  Timer.prototype.start = function start() {
    var _this = this;

    this.now = Date.now();
    this.interval = window.setInterval(function () {
      return _this.update();
    }, this.resolution);
  };

  Timer.prototype.reset = function reset() {
    this.update();
    this.ms = 0;
  };

  Timer.prototype.stop = function stop() {
    this.update();
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = null;
  };

  Timer.prototype.update = function update() {
    this.ms += this.delta(Date.now());
    console.log("%d ms - %0.2f sec", this.ms, this.ms / 1000);
  };

  return Timer;
})();

var t = new Timer(50);
t.start();

// in ~5 seconds, reset the timer once
setTimeout(function () {
  return t.reset();
}, 5000);

// in ~10 seconds, pause the timer
setTimeout(function () {
  return t.stop();
}, 10000);

// in ~12 seconds, resume the timer (without reset)
setTimeout(function () {
  return t.start();
}, 12000);
```