# Javascript - best of 2 ways to create a simple clock

Tags: javascript

So I'm creating a clock for my website, and I have thought of 2 approaches to it..

1)

```
var today = new Date();
this.start = function() {
    this.update();
    setInterval(this.update,1000);
}
this.update = function() {
    today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 1);
}
```

or

2)

```
var today = new Date();
this.start = function() {
    this.update();
    setInterval(this.update,1000);
}
this.update = function() {
    today = new Date();
}
```

Which would be better? Generating a new date every second or just updating? (or perhaps a third approach)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much better for you to use `new Date()` for each loop because the interval used on `setInterval` will not be 100% constant.

`new Date()` will be accurate regardless of `setInterval` variances

---

Here's a snippet from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31499056/633183) I gave a couple days ago. It explains the issue with using `setInterval` with fixed-value incrementing (or decrementing).

> Beware of creating timers that increment with a fixed value

In your code, you have

```
setTimeout(() => this.count--, 1000);
```

The intention is for you to decrement your `count` property once every second, but this is not the behavior you will be guaranteed.

Check out this little script

```
var state = {now: Date.now()};

function delta(now) {
  let delta = now - state.now;
  state.now = now;
  return delta;
}

setInterval(() => console.log(delta(Date.now())), 1000);

// Output
1002
1000
1004
1002
1002
1001
1002
1000
```

We used `setInterval(fn, 1000)` but the actual interval varies a couple milliseconds each time.

The problem is exaggerated if you do things like switch your browser's focus to a different tab, open a new tab, etc. Look at these more sporadic numbers

```
1005 // close to 1000 ms
1005 // ...
1004 // a little variance here
1004 // ...
1834 // switched focus to previous browser tab
1231 // let timer tab run in background for a couple seconds
1082 // ...
1330 // ...
1240 // ...
2014 // switched back to timer tab
1044 // switched to previous tab
2461 // rapidly switched to many tabs below
1998 // ...
2000 // look at these numbers...
1992 // not even close to the 1000 ms that we set for the interval
2021 // ...
1989 // switched back to this tab
1040 // ...
1003 // numbers appear to stabilize while this tab is in focus
1004 // ...
1005 // ...
```

So, this means you can't rely upon your `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) function getting run once per `1000` ms. `count` will be decremented with much variance depending on a wide variety of factors.

To work around this, you need to use a delta. That means before each "tick" of your timer, you need to take a timestamp using `Date.now`. On the next tick, take a new timestamp and subtract your previous timestamp from the new one. That is your `delta`. Using this value, add it to the Timer's total `ms` to get the *precise* number of milliseconds the timer has been running for.

---

Comment: Nice, thanks! The idea is to just update a simple clock so I won't need to find out the delta.. but your answer is very complete. I noticed that when using settimeout the clock would get out of sync after some time

Comment: Yeah, in your case, you won't need to compute the delta, just make sure you're not using the `today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 1);` variety. That is a fixed-value increment and will get out of sync very quickly.

Comment: Also look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for *all* of your JavaScript date/time needs.